# zeromq SYNCHRONOUS REQUEST/RESPONSE fifo

Tags: java, zeromq

I have a server for zeromq reply like this:

```
public static void runDocRequirementServer() throws Exception {
    ZMQ.Socket.bind("tcp://localhost:5555");

    //boolean serverBusy = false;

    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        // Wait for next request from the client
        //byte[] request = ZeroMqServerFactory.ZMQ_SERVER.recv(0);
        //System.out.println("Received Hello");


        //boolean hasRecieveMore = ZeroMqServerFactory.ZMQ_SERVER.hasReceiveMore();



        byte[] recv = ZeroMqServerFactory.ZMQ_SERVER.recv();



        //serverBusy = true;

        System.out.println("RECV MESSAGE!");

        Object receivedObject = null;

        //DocRequirement docRequirementRecv = null;
        try {
            receivedObject = ByteObjectManipulator.deserialize(recv);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        if(!(receivedObject instanceof DocRequirement)) {
            continue;
        }


        DocRequirement docRequirement = (DocRequirement) receivedObject;


        System.out.println("Received: " + docRequirement.getId());

        //docRequirementRecv.setId(99);

        DocProduced docProduced = new DocProduced();
        docProduced.setId(docRequirement.getId() + 1);

        byte[] objectSerialized = ByteObjectManipulator.serialize(docProduced);

        // Do some 'work'
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Send reply back to client
        //String reply = "World";
        ZeroMqServerFactory.ZMQ_SERVER.send(objectSerialized);

        //serverBusy = false;
    }



    try {
        ZeroMqServerFactory.restartServer();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ZeroMqServerFactory.stopServer();
    }

}
```

I have a client like this:

```
private DocProduced sendMessage(String protocol, String ip, String port, int receiveTimeout, DocRequirement docRequirement) throws MessageSendingException {

    String connectString = null;

    try {
        connectString = ConnectStringProducer.produceConnectString(protocol, ip, port);
    } catch (ConnectionPropertyException e) {
        throw new MessageSendingException(e);
    }

    String uniqueIdentity = identity.getUser().getLogin() + "_" + System.nanoTime();

    byte[] objectSerialized = new byte[0];
    try {
        objectSerialized = ByteObjectManipulator.serialize(docRequirement);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new MessageSendingException(e);
    }


    //init context
    ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context(1);

    // create request socket
    ZMQ.Socket client = context.socket(ZMQ.REQ);
    client.setIdentity(uniqueIdentity.getBytes());
    client.setReceiveTimeOut(receiveTimeout);
    client.connect(connectString);

    //send object
    client.send(objectSerialized);


    //wait to receive

    byte[] receivedByteArray;

    try{
        receivedByteArray = client.recv();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        client.close();
        context.term();

        throw new MessageSendingException(e);
    }


    if(receivedByteArray == null) {
        client.close();
        context.term();

        throw new MessageSendingException("Received data null");
    }



    Object receivedObject;

    try {
        receivedObject = ByteObjectManipulator.deserialize(receivedByteArray);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        client.close();
        context.term();

        throw new MessageSendingException(e);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        client.close();
        context.term();

        throw new MessageSendingException(e);
    }


    if(!(receivedObject instanceof DocProduced)) {
        client.close();
        context.term();

        throw new MessageSendingException("Wrong reply received from server");
    }


    //cast
    DocProduced docProduced = (DocProduced) receivedObject;


    client.close();
    context.term();

    return docProduced;
}
```

Now If i send three requests in a row, they are not getting received by the reply socket serially. most of the times i get 1,3,2 rather than 1,2,3. Is there any way to instruct the reply socket to reply in a fifo manner? please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the client making all the requests on the same thread?  Are you creating a new context for each request?

Comment: thanks for your comment, the ccodes are already there. Just to make it clear, yes different threads and also new context for each request. But the codes are there to see. That's why I posted them, I hated to ask a verbose question, but at the end posted it.

Comment: Also I think if in a request reply situation, if fifo can't be achieved, then zeromq is useless for synchronized connection scenario.

Comment: I'm asking the question because in REQ-REP, FIFO is the only way it works, which means something deeply weird is going on with your code.  The first thing I would do is have one context for the client process.  What's ZeroMqServerFactory?

Comment: Wait, if you have different threads, how do you know which request is getting sent in which order, since they can execute and send the requests in any order?  Are you saying you have a whole bunch of threads, but you want them to send their requests in a fixed order?

Comment: ok i misundersood your question, I am running the client method from a seam 2 based web application page (one single page has three buttons, ie). so, i guess they are all being thrown from the same thread if i am not mistaken. I am just clicking the buttons in the order of 1,2,3 the rest of the information is in the code. thanks

Comment: Ok, and why do you think the responses are coming back incorrectly?  Is it because System.out.println("Received: " + docRequirement.getId());
is printing the IDs out of order?

Comment: my friend, i dont know the answer, thats why i posted the question. I posted the codes for you to test them in your own environment and see what is going wrong. if i knew what is going wrong, i wouldnt have asked the question here. Please use the codes and let me know what your results are.

Comment: I mean, what indicates to you that the responses are coming back in the wrong order?  The way ZeroMQ is written, it's basically impossible to be happening at the messaging level, and I can't run the above code in my environment, as it's not a self-contained example.